# iOS: Getting height of views with programatically added constraints as only indicator

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiscrollview, constraints, programmatically-created

Hello there fellow iOS programmers. While creating an app I've ran into a problem I can't seem to find an answer to. Let's lay it out:

I'm creating a UIViewController with a UIScrollView as it's only child. Inside this view I have a UIView, and inside of this there is a list of UIViews with UILabels inside them. As you all know you need to specify a contentSize for a UIScrollView.
The problem is that the list needs to be dynamic with it's content, and I therefore have no way to know the views heights beforehand. I'm adding all views with constraints where the height is set to ">=0".
When I later try to set the height of the UIScrollView I need to either get the height of the UIView that the list is inside, or get the origin.y and height of the last view in the list. This of course needs to be ready by the time the view is displayed to the user.

I've currently tried view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize), which returned 0; view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize), which returned 10000; and view.origin.y + view.frame.height, which also returns 0. It seems to me like the constraints haven't taken effect yet.

I've tried setting both constraints and UIScollView.contentSize from viewDidLoad(). I've also tried to set constraints in viewDidLoad and setting contentSize in viewWillAppear; this yielded the same results. Setting constraints in viewWillAppear and setting contentSize in viewDidLoad only caused a crash.

**Bottom-line:** When should I set up the UIScrollView.contentSize if I want to get view.height or similar methods to return a correct result, while at the same time be ready by the time the user sees the view?

Btw, I'm making this app in Swift, so answers in this language is preferred, but I'm able to translate from Objective-C to Swift; post in whatever suits you best.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> As you all know you need to specify a `contentSize` for a `UIScrollView`.

No, as [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) says, the constraints between the scroll view and its subviews are "interpreted as the *content size* of the scroll view" (emphasis added). This is a boon, because you no longer have to mess around with `contentSize` if doing auto-layout. Just set the constraints for the scroll view's subviews and the content size takes care of itself. This leverages the labels' intrinsic size (and make sure that the label's `numberOfLines` to zero).

The only trick is that it sometimes cannot figure out the correct width of the labels (because the trailing constraint is to the scroll view's content size, it will sometimes make the scroll view a horizontally scrolling one). You can remedy this by either manually setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` or by setting a width constraint between the label and the scroll view's *superview.*

Personally, while I understand the inclination to add the `UIView` containers between the scroll view and the labels, I'd suggest losing them unless you need them for some other reason. IMHO, it simply complicates the constraints unnecessarily. It's hairy enough as it is. Obviously, if these containers bear other utility for you, then go ahead and keep them (and they'll work fine), but if you're doing this simply for the sake of the constraints, you might consider eliminating them.

Comment: Could you go into any more depth on how to avoid the UIScrollView from scrolling horizontally? I tried to set a specific width constraint to the UIViews(They are necessary), and when that didn't work i tried setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth for the UILabels. When this didn't work out I tried to set sv.contentSize.width manually, but this also had no effect. What am I doing wrong? Could you please post example code?

Comment: When using auto layout, don't try to set `frame` or `contentSize` manually. Use constraints. And to set width of label, either use `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` or use constraint, like I did below. FYI, while I generally do it in IB, the only way to show you in code is to implement the constraints programmatically, which I did in this demo: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/2211d9947b4ad6109659 It's easier to do in IB, but harder for me to demonstrate, like I did in the above link.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're getting too caught up in this, turn on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and you can do everything old-school, playing with widths, calculate heights manually, etc. You just seem to lose a bit of flexibility in the process.

Comment: I'm already creating all constraints programatically, and as I mentioned I tried without touching frame or contentSize at first. This still didn't work out.

I would really prefer to avoid turning on translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints because the highly varying text lengths would make this a difficult and frustrating process.

Btw, I don't know if this matters, but I'm using constraintsWithVisualFormat.

Comment: Did you try the code from my gist? That was a working demonstration in which I did everything programmatically?

Comment: I tried to use it, but what is scrollViewSuperView, and how I can use it's Swift alternative in my own code?

Comment: That's just whatever you're adding the scroll view to. I didn't want to presume that you just added it as subview to `self.view`, but presumably that's where you're adding it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll be testing the code, and seeing if I can translate the it into my project now. I'll get back to you with the results soon. :)

Comment: After 20+ hours of frustrating work I finally figured out why it didn't work for me. It turns out I had forgot to add a | at the end of the visual y constraint! It works now though, so thank you very much for your help. :D